# Странное поведение валидатора HTML

Tags: html, валидация

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2F вот тест сайта https://youtube.com, валидатору почему-то побарабану на теги с названием типа `ytd-app`? Такого тега если я не ошибаюсь не существует. может я что-то недопераю?

спасибо мне помогло

Comment: Теги с дефисом разрешены любые

Comment: а такой тег валидный? `<-sampletag></-sampletag>`

Comment: нет, [в стандарте указано, что вначале должна быть только английская буковка](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#valid-custom-element-name)